# ajax post spring mvc controller return http 404

Tags: ajax, spring, post, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

I am getting and posting some user informations(json objects) from/to the spring mvc controller,I can get the right info via the http get request,but I got an 404 error when I send a ajax post request,can you show me where am I wrong,any suggetions would be highly appreciated!

```
   $.ajax({ data:JSON.stringify(item),
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json",
       url: "/idm/rest",

        success: function(response, textStatus){
            item.id = response.id;
            if (success_callback != null)
            {
                 success_callback(response, textStatus);
            }
            result = response; 
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //this;   
            if (error_callback != null)
            {
                 error_callback(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
            result = null;
        }
    });
```

2) spring mvc controller:

```
@RestController  
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class JxUserController {
@Autowired 
@Qualifier(value="appservice")
JxAppService svc;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={ "application/json"})
public JxUserEx find(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    return svc.newUserService().findById(id);
}  

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<JxUserEx> find(JxQuerySYST0011 querysyst0011) {
    com.opencenter.idm.service.user.JxUserService users = svc.newUserService();
    return users.find(querysyst0011);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/meta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public JxQueryMetadata findTotal() {
    return svc.newUserService().count();
} 

@RequestMapping(value= "", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public @ResponseBody JxUserEx create(@RequestBody JxUserEx syst0011) {
    com.opencenter.idm.service.user.JxUserService users =   svc.newUserService();
    return users.create(syst0011);
}
```

[ajax post request and the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Krg.png)
[spring mvc controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTqSW.png)

Comment: Where is your port number? Also, please post error messages in the post itself, not as images and relevant code only.

Comment: thanks for your response!  my url is:http://localhost:80/idm/rest/user, the error messages as follow:POST http://localhost/idm/rest 404 (Not Found)k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:formatted:3815n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:formatted:3592AppService.add @ user-v3.js:276Vue.methods.onSave @ user-v3.js:599(anonymous function) @ vue.js:305Vue.component.methods.onSubmitClick @ user-v3.js:397(anonymous function) @ vue.js:306(anonymous function) @ VM115:3handler @ vue.js:9283handler @ vue.js:6017

Comment: I use the same url:http://localhost:80/idm/rest/user,I can get the user info from the controller,But when I post some user infos to the controller,I got 404 error,why?I am going crazy.